# Change not equal sign shape Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, comparison

I'm using Overleaf. I want to use `≠` the way it is. A `/` passign in the middle of `=`. I checked various links same as [their  documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/project/611e997c668ec230d83e5512) in my document, the `/` sign starts in the very beginning of `=` and is something like `/=` rather than `≠`

```
\begin{equation}\label{e3}
F\,(x\textprime) \neq y 
\end{equation}
```

which yields:
[image]

This is what I intended:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide us with an image of the output, together with some code we can use to replicate this?

Comment: Okay, what does `\show\neq` reveal in the `.log`? We can't replicate the visuals with the code you show. Can you provide a minimal document (starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`) that allows us to replicate the issue on our end?

Comment: overleaf is not related to this, it is just hosting a standard tex distribution.

Comment: why are you using `\textprime` in math? the output you show for `\neq` is clearly broken so you presumably have redefined it in code you have not shown, that is not the standard  output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hello. I installed several packages and several other commands. The document is nearly 10 pages and I'm relatively new to latex. What else do I need to include? Because every time I encountered the problem I just searched and copy-paste the answer and worked. I already had some problems with some signs shape and by searching I solved it. It is possible that I have changed some signs without knowing it. What else should I be looking for to include in my questions? Like what kinds of other commands. Thanks.
Thanks.

Comment: @Werner Hello. I used another template in overleaf because I had some problems creating a document from scratch. This is what `\show\neq` shows in log:

`> \neq=macro:->\protect \neq  .l.35 \show\neq`
And the sign is just fine. So I clearly have changed something and I would need to know what that is in order to include it in the question. Thanks.

Comment: you do not need to add anything you need to remove whatever code you have added that broke neq. we can not tell you that unless you show the code. it is easy for you to make a small example to add to your question. start with a document with your current preamble plus the math expression you show. then delete anything from the preamble that you can delete checking at each stage the problem still occurs

Comment: and replace \textprime with '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a simple `\neq` should produce what you're asking for and there's no need to reinvent the wheel. But in case you encounter problems with that, a workaround consists of combining `=` and `/` in math mode, using `\mkern` with some negative value like in the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\noteq}{=\mkern-16mu /\mkern 8mu}

\begin{document}
    $A \noteq B$ \quad \Large $A \noteq B$ \quad \Huge $A \noteq B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there's a slight difference between `\neq` and this command, as you can see below:

[image: \neq vs this command]

Comment: why not `$A \neq B$ \quad \Large $A \neq B$ \quad \Huge $A \neq B$`  ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're absolutely right, but It just seemed fair to answer exactly the question *without* using `\neq`.

Comment: the danger is future readers who might be tempted to copy this code. Which is not needed unless they have the same (so far unknown) code from the OP that broke `\neq`

Comment: I understand. Should I delete my answer so? I may edit it to point out that `\neq` is already working and stating that my solution is only a workaround.

Comment: no need to delete (actually you can't delete as it's accepted:-)  I guess it got the OP going again. I think this comment thread under it is fine as a warning to other readers.

Comment: Or write a warning at the top of your answer